# Database not being copied from assets folder to device

Tags: android, sqlite, assets

I have a .db file in my `assets` folder. I've copied it to the `data/data/<packagename>/databases/` folder in the emulator and its working fine..

But when i run it on device it force closes. It is showing

```
SQLite exception: no such table: tbl_user
```

Here is my code..

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DatabaseHelper() {

            super(dataContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);

            DB_PATH = "/data/data/"
                    + dataContext.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                    + "/databases/";

            Log.d("PATH", DB_PATH);

            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            if (!dbExist) {

                this.getReadableDatabase();
                try {
                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.d("Error", e.toString());
                }
            }

        }

        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            InputStream inFile = dataContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            while ((length = inFile.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            // Close the streams
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            inFile.close();
        }

        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME);

            return dbFile.exists();

        }
```

Should i have to do something else to copy that db to the device???

Thanks..

Comment: I really recommend using `SQLiteAssetHelper`, as it has this whole process debugged, rather than rolling your own: https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper

Comment: please check this link http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got the answer... :)

From here..

http://www.anddev.org/networking-database-problems-f29/missing-table-in-sqlite-with-specific-version-of-desire-hd-t50364.html

it was the problem with version 2.3.6... it was working with other devices... just added three lines to solve the problem...

```
boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        SQLiteDatabase db_Read = null;
        if (!dbExist) 
        {
            db_Read = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
            db_Read.close();

            try 
            {
                copyDataBase();
            } 
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
                Log.d("Error", e.toString());
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the database file .db extension in the asset folder  to .png or any other compressed format it will worke in 2.1, 2.2 and above devices