# Android SQLite database into device

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an android application which contains 2 tables. I saw the table under DDMS tab. These two table contains some important data for my application(For example: username and password for 2000 records). But When I install my application on device, I couldn't able to see the table.

Also, In device when I'm running my application it creates a new table. This table contains no records. So when I check for username and password, it return no rows, affect my application.

So I need to copy the two tables into the device at the time of installing apk file. Is there any ways to do this?

Comment: dou you get error(s) if yes what are they?

Comment: No errors the database contains no records

Comment: `when I'm running my application it creates a new table` how does it do that? Thats the point where you have to populate the table.

Comment: if you not have any records it cant be show something to you. try to add one example recort to your db

Comment: @Henry what do you mean?

Comment: If I'm adding any records it will be added. But I need that table with those 2000 records

Comment: Package the data into your application (for example as an asset file). When you create the DB, insert the records.

Comment: How to package the data into app? can you explain clearly?

Comment: Suggestion: Create a signup page.

Comment: Not possible. I need to copy the database onto the device. Is there no ways?

Comment: You can use JSON or XML to store your information. Place this file into assets directory. And when your app created database you could fill it with your information.

Comment: Yes it is possible: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951805/how-to-access-an-existing-sqlite-database-in-android

Comment: @Ares such a valuable idea. Thank you

Comment: mentioning path: which path? it doesn't solve my problem

Comment: I faced with the same problem and I didn't find any solution for that. So I decided to store my data inside XML file and parsed it if necessary.

Comment: Place your DB which contains your login information in assets and provide the path mate!

Comment: @Areas can you post your sample code please?

Comment: @Chronically Instance If I provided path to asset, will it accessible in device. I think the path may vary

Comment: @Areas If I saved it as JSON, can I modify it in the future?  How do i access that JSON in my code

Comment: The path will not vary! How do you conclude a path can vary? Yes assets folder is meant for such type of access. Its the reason why you have an assets folder.

Comment: @Chronically Insane. You mean, I should copy my database and paste it on asset folder and give path in my code?

Comment: @Areas If you don't mine can you post your sample code

Comment: There is a lot of code. You should read about working with XML and JSON. You can change XML nodes as well as in sqllite

Comment: I need to copy as JSON. But how to save the file?

Comment: @Ares Thanks, I found that. I;ll try

Comment: I have created it by my self. Note: do not store passwords and logins in database, xml and so on. It's not safe!

Comment: check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14081085/database-not-being-copied-from-assets-folder-to-device

Answer (score -2):

You can fetching your database tables records using

```
SQLiteDatabase myDB = this.openOrCreateDatabase("test.sqlite",
          SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);
Cursor c = myDB.rawQuery("select a, b from abc", null);
```

Comment: the answer is not eligible. You should read question more carefully